# Use ResultSet value in another jsp file

Tags: mysql, jsp, session, resultset

I´m trying to use resultset value in another jsp file, but i´m getting `null` on the website.

```
<%
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "root", "root");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users");
        String var = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            var = rs.getString(2);
        }
       session.setAttribute("var1", var);
        response.sendRedirect("Select.jsp");

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
%>
```

Select.jsp:

```
<% out.println(request.getParameter("var1")); %>
```

The selct1.jsp is showing `null`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you sat the parameter using `setAttribute` but you are trying to fetch using `getParameter`,

Fetch results with `getAttributes` methods:-

```
<% out.println((String)request.getAttribute("var1")); %>
```

or with

```
<% out.println(session.getAttribute("var1")); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are setting the value in `session` scope :

```
session.setAttribute("var1", var);
```

But you are trying to get it from `request` scope :

```
request.getParameter("var1")
```

So keep same scope (either both `session` or both `request`).

Also, you should avoid using scriplets in JSP as it is not recommended.